# If $U$ is a unit vector, why is the matrix $UU^\top$ idempotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, involutions

The title says it all: if $U$ is a unit vector, why is the matrix $UU^\top$ idempotent?

In other words, why is $UU^\top$ the matrix of a projection?

I am also interested in understanding the "physical" meaning of $UU^\top$. It is clear that $I-2UU^\top$ is an orthogonal symmetry with respect to the hyperplane $U^\perp$ so I could of course expand $(I-2UU^\top)^2=I$ but I would like another, more intuitive, explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** By associativity,
$$
(UU^T)(UU^T) = U(U^TU)U^T
$$

---

The transformation $UU^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the span of the unit vector $U$.  As an illustrative example, you should consider $U = (1,0,\dots,0)^T$.  All such maps look like this up to an orthogonal change of basis.

Comment: $U^\top U=||U||^2=1$, got it, thank you.

Comment: How about that second part?

Comment: Oh I understood it, otherwise I would have asked. In fact it helped me figuring out what I was missing (the fact that $U$ was unit).

Comment: Great!${}{}{}{}$

Comment: PS: you even take care of after-sales service, that's very kind of you!