# How can I prove that a specific symmetric matrix $P = I - \frac{uu^T}{u^T u}$ is idempotent?

Tags: matrices, idempotents

Given the matrix $$P = I - \frac{uu^T}{u^T u},$$ how can I prove that $P = P^2$?

I know that the matrix is symmetric, but how can I use this information to prove that it's idempotent?

Comment: Have you computed $P^2$?

Comment: What is the quotient of $uu^T$ by $u^Tu$? If $A$ is idempotent, then also $I-A$.

Comment: Act twice with $P$ with an arbitrary vector and see what happesn!

Comment: @DietrichBurde: $u^T u$ is simply the standard inner product $\langle u, u\rangle$.

Comment: Ah, then we are done. Because then $P=I-A$ and $A$ is idempotent - see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466094/if-u-is-a-unit-vector-why-is-the-matrix-uu-top-idempotent).

Comment: Just compute $P^2$ and show that it is the same as $P$.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks guys